# Type mismatch with Offset function Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I'm new to VBA macros, the function has to read a formula, write the result to `resultCell` and go down to have other values in the formula. Everything was fine, but it only counted the first values (BJ4-AV4), so that it counts further BJ5, BJ6, BJ7... I used `offset(i,0)` so it should go down. I already used `offset` to write the result, but when I entered it to go from cell to cell in the formula, it broke. I hope the code helps make sense of the nonsense I wrote

```vb
Sub avg()
    Dim firstCell, resultCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set firstCell = Worksheets(1).Range("BJ4")
    Set resultCell = Worksheets(1).Range("CA4")

    For i = 0 To 502
        ' go to 12 left
        If firstCell.Offset(i, -12).Value > 0 Then
            resultCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = (firstCell.Offset(i, 0).Value - firstCell.Offset(i, -12).Value) / 6
        ElseIf firstCell.Offset(i, -10).Value > 0 Then
        ' if previous is null go to 10 left
            resultCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = (firstCell.Offset(i, 0).Value - firstCell.Offset(i, -10).Value) / 5
        ElseIf firstCell.Offset(i, -14).Value > 0 Then
        ' if previous is null go to 14 left
            resultCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = (firstCell.Offset(i, 0).Value - firstCell.Offset(i, -14).Value) / 7
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rpRM.png)

Comment: What is in those cells? Strings? Errors?

Comment: If any value in your cells is not a number, then it will break on the maths functions.

Comment: @DS_London all cells is nums

Comment: Which line produces the error? What is the value of i at that point?

Comment: @DS_London runtime err '13' (type mismatch) on string `resultCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = (firstCell.Offset(i, 0).Value - firstCell.Offset(i, -12).Value) / 6`

Comment: Your code works perfect for me. It looks like a value in the cells is not being recognized as numeric. When the error arises, what is the value of `i` at that exact moment?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns could the error be because there is a formula in the cell that returns a number?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns >what is the value of i at that exact moment? How do I know that?

Comment: when the error arises, click on Debug, and then just hover your mouse over the variable. Wait some seconds and a popup should appear with the value. That is the row number (starting at BJ4) that may hold something wrong. And no, a formula is not a problem as long as it really returns a numeric value

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns OMG I just did too many iterations of the loop, thanks!